# C#: Help understanding <<property>> in UML Class Diagrams

Tags: c#, class, uml, diagram

I am currently doing a project where we have to make code from UML diagrams. I understand the anatomy of a UML class diagram but I'm having trouble understanding what `<<property>>` means and how to implement it into my code.

[image]

Comment: That just looks like a Python design gone the C path ;-)

Answer (score 6):

`<<property>>` is a stereotype (like most things in UML embraced by `<< >>`). In this case it indicates that you shall implement getters and setters for the accordingly named privately owned attributes of the class. E.g. for the `Status` you would implement `getStatus` and `setStatus` (or whatever is used in the target language for that purpose). As there's also the constraint `{ readonly }` for `Name` you shall just implement `getName`. You probably have to guess that the attribute's name is `_bookName`.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is the answer, I just couldn't wrap my head around it. One last question I just faced; When I come across a method in Book() like ReturnBook() and it gives the data types Timespan, int, and decimal. How is it possible to assign 3 datatypes to a method?

Comment: That's a bit too difficult to answer in a comment. Please ask a new question for that. I'll have a look tomorrow (unless someone else answers earlier).

Comment: Since you tagged this as `[C#]`, you should know that _property_ is a first class part of the C# language.  Classes can have properties of any type.  The getters and setters can have different access levels (the getter, public, for example, while the setter is private).  Read-only properties (no setter) and write-only (no getter) properties are available.  If the property has a trivial definition (the getter and setter simply access a private backing field), then you can use an _auto-property_ with a simple, easy to express and understand syntax

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this as `[C#]`, you should know that property is a first-class part of the C# language. Classes can have properties of any type. The getters and setters can have different access levels (the getter, public, for example, while the setter is private). Read-only properties (no setter) and write-only (no getter) properties are available. If the property has a trivial definition (the getter and setter simply access a private backing field), then you can use an auto-property with a simple, easy to express and understand syntax.

```
class MyClass {
    //this is a simple property with a backing field
    private int _someInt = 0;
    public int SomeInt {
        get { return _someInt; }
        set { _someInt = value; }    //"value" is a keyword meaning the rhs of a property set expression
    }

    //this is a similar property as an "auto property", the initializer is optional
    public int OtherInt { get; set; } = 0;

    //this is an auto-property with a public getter, but a protected setter
    public string SomeString { get; protected set; }
}
```

If the setter (or getter) is omitted, the property becomes read-only (or write-only).